# Get selected text from dropdownlist using jQuery [Rails3]

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

**How is correctly to do to get selected text from dropdownlist with using jQuery**

This not work, may be because on the Rails(RoR)

```
$("#select_tag_id option:selected").text();
```

**jquery 1.8**

thanks in advance

Comment: That should work assuming the element exists

Comment: <script>$("#user_warning_email_balance option:selected").text();
</script> no work  <select id="user_warning_email_balance" name="user[warning_email_balance]"><option value="5">5</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="20">20</option></select>

Comment: looks like your script is executing before your html is in the page. Try swapping the order, and wrap the call in a console.log and see if it shows up in the console

Comment: It works - http://jsfiddle.net/Nmuqf/

Comment: Thank you @Justin Bicknell and how to make that text dynamically updating on change select

Comment: No problem, here is how to use the change event http://jsfiddle.net/Nmuqf/3/ - If you update your question with the original code I will add an aswer